# Secured Local host not able to get an access to website (food2fork) api

Tags: reactjs, https, ssl-certificate

I'm making an API request to food2fork website I have secured my localhost using ngork but I'm not able to get an access. Its keep giving me the mixed content warning and blocking the API request. 
Can you please tell me where am I going wrong.?

Comment: this sounds like a  [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue more then ssl. what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Its giving the error mixed content: the page at 'page name'  was loaded over Https but requested insecure 'item name' . This content should also be served on Https. Do I need to activate cors?

Comment: I also clicked shield icon and allowed scripts from unauthenticated sources and warning went from red to yellow but still didn't get access to the API .